# "SO is not customer support for [your favorite company]", but where is the boundary?

Tags: discussion

WRT this question and its answer: [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

One may possibly say that with Java-related question, you should ask Oracle. Any .NET-related question goes to Microsoft. Etc, etc.
For instance, a question like "when is this feature going to be implemented in C#" or "why doesn't Java support this feature".
So, how do I know that my question belongs to SO or not? Where is the boundary?

Comment: See the [on topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what types of questions can and can't be asked here.

Comment: @Servy it doesn't answer my question. How do you tell that your question is "asking for support" or not?

Comment: You look at the on topic list.  If your question meets the criteria of things you can ask about, and doesn't meet any of the criteria of things you can't ask about, then it's potentially on topic here.

Comment: What did you not understand from the FAQ?  It described what types of questions do belong here and what don't, and linked to other pages for further details?  (Including the on topic page, because that's how you determine what's on topic here.)

Comment: With respect to your two example questions: those are things only Oracle or MSFT (respectively) *could* know. If your question could *only* be answered by the company providing the tech, then its customer support. Also, in general, asking to predict the future on SE will get your question closed quickly.

Answer (score 16):

It's a simpler question than you may realize.

**Are you looking for *product* support?**

We're *not* going to be able to help you.  Some companies *do* have an active presence here on Stack Overflow, but that's only in the context of questions which are on-topic - notably, questions involving programming facets involving their product are going to be better received than questions about their product.

Note:  Programming something in Java is not the same as "have a Java license from Oracle and need to escalate a ticket to them".

Since you've added examples, both

> When is this feature going to be implemented in C#?

and

> Why doesn't Java support this feature?

...would be easily considered "off-topic" since they're more subjective than objective and largely were decisions made by the actual language writers, and we lack *most* context into what their decisions were.